# validate with keypress enter

Tags: jquery, validation, input, keypress

i have a problem. I will validation my Testsite. 
So i have 4 input field to which i want to check.

My check work but i write all 4 inputs i get a alert error that is not what i want, because i need the form action link.

Here my Code:

```
var pin1 = jQuery('#pin1').val();
    var pin2 = jQuery('#pin2').val();
    var pin3 = jQuery('#pin3').val();
    var pin4 = jQuery('#pin4').val();

    var pin = pin1 + pin2 + pin3 + pin4;

   $("input").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {

            event.preventDefault();

           if(pin == ""){
                alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Inputfelder aus");
            }else{
                $("form").submit();
            }



        }
    });
```

And here my Testsite: http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/login.html?email=HTML5_APP_dmarkstaedter@iscope.de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of input fields have to be read on the event handler, in your case you are reading the `pin` values on dom ready... which means it have the default values in the `pin` fields which could be empty strings

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        var pin1 = jQuery('#pin1').val();
        var pin2 = jQuery('#pin2').val();
        var pin3 = jQuery('#pin3').val();
        var pin4 = jQuery('#pin4').val();
        var pin = pin1 + pin2 + pin3 + pin4;

        event.preventDefault();
        if(pin == ""){
            alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Inputfelder aus");
        }else{
            $("form").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the values of your inputs *inside* your keypress event, as it stands you are checking the values on DOM load rather than at the time of the key press.

```
   $("input").keypress(function(event) {
        var pin1 = jQuery('#pin1').val();
        var pin2 = jQuery('#pin2').val();
        var pin3 = jQuery('#pin3').val();
        var pin4 = jQuery('#pin4').val();

        var pin = pin1 + pin2 + pin3 + pin4;


        if (event.which == 13) {

            event.preventDefault();

           if(pin == ""){
                alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Inputfelder aus");
            }else{
                $("form").submit();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update or create the variables of input values within your keypress function.
At the moment the variables are set when the page loads, so the pin variable will always be empty when you press enter.
You want to check the contents of the variables after the keypress is done.

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pin1 = jQuery('#pin1').val();
        var pin2 = jQuery('#pin2').val();
        var pin3 = jQuery('#pin3').val();
        var pin4 = jQuery('#pin4').val();
        var pin = pin1 + pin2 + pin3 + pin4;

        if(pin == ""){
            alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Inputfelder aus");
        }else{
            $("form").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // every time you press enter the values must be renewed

        var pin1 = jQuery('#pin1').val();
        var pin2 = jQuery('#pin2').val();
        var pin3 = jQuery('#pin3').val();
        var pin4 = jQuery('#pin4').val();
        var pin = pin1 + pin2 + pin3 + pin4;

        if ($.trim(pin).length !== 4) { 
          // remove white space and check if 4 characters
            alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Inputfelder aus");
        } else {
            $("form").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All the posted answers use an inefficient query practice. You should **not** query for the elements in each keypress. Use jQuery selectors once and store them in variables:

```
var pin1 = $('#pin1'), pin2 = $('#pin2'), pin3 = $('#pin3'), pin4 = $('#pin4');


$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pin = pin1.val() + pin2.val() + pin3.val() + pin4.val()

        if(pin == ""){
            alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Inputfelder aus");
        } else {
            $("form").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

However, this code still **won't quite work as you had hoped.** If the user enters a value in one of the fields and hits enter, the `submit()` method will be called.

Instead of checking for *invalid* input, try checking for *valid* input. I also made some other best-practice changes:

```
var $inputs = $('.login_input'), $form = $('#pin_login');

$inputs.keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var pin = $inputs.map(function(i,ele){return ele.value}).get().join('');

        if(pin.length == 4) {
            $form.submit();
        } else {
            alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Inputfelder aus");
        }
    }
});
```